# How to efficiently write features using specflow?

Tags: .net, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I am working on a SpecFlow project in C#, and I want to make the process of adding scenarios more user-friendly for non-technical individuals, such as product owners. Currently, the process involves manually creating and editing feature files, which can be challenging for someone without technical expertise.

Is there a way to simplify this process and provide a more intuitive interface or tool that allows non-technical users to easily add scenarios to the SpecFlow project? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that enables the writer to be aware of existing steps and prevent the creation of duplicate scenarios.

Currently, we utilize the SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio, which offers autocomplete functionality for existing steps during scenario creation. However, our development process still demands a fundamental understanding of version control tools.

Comment: At this time I don't know of anything that simplifies this. To use SpecFlow, you basically need Visual Studio. I know that some limited plugins exist for Visual Studio Code. I've played around with them, but nothing that is functionally complete.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to search some possible solutions online.
Since your target is for a common tool that can be used by both the developers and non-technical users like Product Owners.

You may want to look into the following features of a Jira plugin

https://behavepro.app/features

One of the features that I think would be useful to you based on the link above is

**Source code integration:**

- Two-way sync between Jira and Git repositories
  Scenario edits in Jira are published directly to feature files in your Git repository in real time, and feature file changes are synced to Jira. Native support for Feature Branching, GitFlow and Trunk-based development means there’s no need to change your repository setup.

The above features means that any modifications done by Product Owners can be synced to your code and any modifications in your feature files will be synced to Jira maintaining one single source of truth for your project.

Although, this option is paid, I am not sure if there are other tools/plugins that are free out there.